# How to configure a joystick under linux in BGE?

Tags: game-engine, linux

I am trying to use a joystick in BGE under linux.
Version is 2.76b on Ubuntu 16.04.

I can see that the joystick is working under jstest-gtk, which captures the input from /dev/input/js0.

In BGE i have a joystick sensor connected to a "Quit Game" Actuator, hoping a simple button press would End the game I started before.
But no input is taken from the joystick.

Can someone tell, how to verify, that blender uses /dev/input/jsX?
Some other options? Does someone has it working under different device?

Comment: I am running into the same issue with ubuntu 16.04! I have found jstest-gtk works and also python script: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html so I know my xbox 360 controller works in linux but BGE does not recognize input. Anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the thing, I found the joystick input works in blender 2.72b and 2.71 in ubuntu 16.04 but not 2.76b or the latest 2.78.  I found out this has also been reported in windows: https://developer.blender.org/D1484 .  This should be reported as occurring in linux as well as windows, idk how to report it, can anyone report this additional bug info?  if not I'll try to.  This is more of a workaround than an answer but until the bug is fixed perhaps this can be the answer.

Comment: Well done, thx for figuring that out. Linux is mentioned in the description of the issue and they are taking care of it.